# How to implement my own analytics for app?

Tags: android, analytics

I want to implement my own analytics for android app. How should I decide when to make server calls with the collected information, so that I don't
 ( or minimize )  consume user bandwidth?

Comment: That's a really subjective question, i.e. it depends entirely on what information you are wanting to gather, how often it is likely to change, and what granularity of change is important to you.

Comment: I want to gather each and every interaction of the user with the app. But I don't want to make server calls during user interaction. Also, I don't want to loose any of the information.